# Inequalities of Norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

The exercise goes as follows: Show that $||x||_\infty \le ||x||_2 \le ||x||_1$. Which I believe I proved--

W.L.O.G., suppose $max |x_i| = |x_1|\ \ |x_k| = \sqrt{x_k^2} \le \sqrt{x_1^2 +...+x_n^2}\ \ \therefore\, ||x||_\infty \le ||x||_2$. Note that $|x_1|+...+|x_n| = \sqrt{x_1^2} + ... + \sqrt{ x_n^2} \ge \sqrt{x_1^2 +...+x_n^2}\ \ \therefore\ ||x||_1 \ge ||x||_2$.

But it then continues to say "Also check that $||x||_1 \le n||x||_\infty$ and $||x||_1 \le \sqrt{n}||x||_2$." This part confuses me, as if $n = 1$ then we are still left with inequality mentioned above. I'm assuming $n$ is equal to the $n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (since it does not specify it otherwise). I would appreciate if someone were to hint me as to what I am missing.

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct- it takes a bit more work to complete the proof.

Comment: Yes, the $n$ here will be the same as the $n$ in the title of the question. Also, when $n = 1$, then other inequalities are *the reverse* of the ones above, thus proving that all three norms agree on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $n$ is the $\color{blue}n$ in $\mathbb{R}^{\color{blue}{n}}$.
- For your first question:$$\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i| \le \sum_{i=1}^n \max_j |x_j|.$$
- Hint for the second question: Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: Thank you so much. I finally see it. $n\ max |x_i| = max |x_1|+...+ max |x_1| \ n $ times.

Comment: yup, that is correct.